# SELECT Query grouping/merging for non-DISTINCT result set

Tags: php, mysql

```
----------   ----------   ----------   ----------    
| t1     |   | t2     |   | t3     |   | t4     |  
----------   ----------   ----------   ----------  
| id     |   | id     |   | id     |   | t1_id  |  
| foo    |   | bar    |   | foobar |   | t2_id  |  
----------   ----------   ----------   | t3_id  |  
                                       ----------
```

I have this set of tables, and with this particular query:

> SELECT foo, bar, foobar FROM t4
>   LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t4.t1_id
>   LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t4.t2_id
>   LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t4.t3_id;

I could then come up with this particular result set:

```
------------------------------       -------------------------------        
| foo    | bar     | foobar  |  =>   | foo      | bar     | foobar |  
------------------------------       -------------------------------  
| x      | y       | a       |       | x        | y       | a      |  
| x      | y       | b       |       |          |         | b      |  
| x      | y       | c       |       |          |         | c      |
------------------------------       -------------------------------
```

QUESTION IS: How can I format my query to *somehow* group those columns with similar entries but not those that are not? Is this even possible in `MySQL`? I'm outputting this through `PHP`, so should I let `PHP` handle its formatting?

*Same question if it should be handled by* `PHP`.

Comment: if you say at the end of query `group by foo, bar` you can change in select list `foobar` to `group_concat(foobar) foobar` to receive it in form `a,b,c`

Comment: I think you should go with PHP side logic i.e store value of first fetch record and match it with other records if found then don't print or show other wise show it.

Comment: Even if it is possible with MySQL, the presentation aspect of your data should not be the responsibility of the database. PHP is much better suited at doing this.

Comment: @splash58, `SELECT group_concat(foo, bar), foobar` ? if so, I've tried that, and it returned only `x | y | a'... nothing else (1 out of 3 expected result set)

Comment: @Prince__ duly noted

Comment: @apokryfos `PHP` it is, but, any pointers I might be missing if it's really possible in mysql? for reference.

Comment: @Valkyrurr `GROUP_CONCAT` as suggested in a response is probably as close as you can get with pure MySQL, if you don't want an elaborate function that formats it the way you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let PHP handle the formatting.  In general, SQL result sets (and tables) represent *unordered* sets.  Your formatting has a particular ordering in mind.

It might help to put the values in one row, with the third column as a "list":

```
SELECT foo, bar, GROUP_CONCAT(foobar) as foobars
FROM t4 LEFT JOIN
     t1
     ON t1.id = t4.t1_id LEFT JOIN
     t2 
     ON t2.id = t4.t2_id LEFT JOIN
     t3
     ON t3.id = t4.t3_id
GROUP BY foo, bar;
```

That said, it *is* possible to do what you want in MySQL (using variables, for instance), but PHP is the better place to do the formatting.

Comment: this! returned the expected results I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct foo, bar, foobar FROM t4
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t4.t1_id
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t4.t2_id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t4.t3_id;
```